# RDbms name and version

Tags: c++, sql, qt, rdbms

I m doing a software in c++ that permit to access to some rdbms with qt library. 
The software is  only for pc.
The software need to know the name of  rdbms and version beacuse the program needs to choose some  sql query to execute. Is there any way to retrieve thisdata in any rdbms?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to retrieve thisdata in any rdbms?

This is specific to each RDBMS - for example, in Oracle, you can do

```
select *
from v$version;
```

but in other RDBMS this view does not exist.

Some possible approaches:

- You need to define connect parameters somewhere anyways. Even they are often RDBMS-specific, so you could simply add another parameter like `SQLFlavor=Oracle` or `SQLFlavor=MySQL` and then use the value of `SQLFlavor` in your code to determine which SQL statement to use
- You can use some heuristics to find out the RDBMS. For example, query the `v$version` view - if it does not exist, you will get an error and you know that it is not Oracle and you can continue with the next try (like `SELECT VERSION()` to see if it is MySQL). Otherwise, you can use the result to find out the concrete Oracle version.

Comment: But in all rdbms are there some method to retrieve this information?